# Create a data entry form with scrolling like Contacts form

Tags: ios, user-interface, scroll

I am using a storyboard, to create a View on which the user can enter data, like creating a contact.

I have tried placing some `UITextField`s on a view, but this way, I have the problem that there will be no scrolling when the iPhone is showing the keyboard at the bottom.

I hope someone can give me some hints about which controls I have to use to create a data entry form like the one for entering contacts in the iPhone.

Comment: You want to disable the scrolling feature or you cannot get the scrolling feature to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place an UIScrollView to your UIView element and then you can add UITextField objects to the UIScrollView as you wish. After doing this, you need to make an IBOutlet property (e.g. scrollView) for your UIScrollView and link them.

Finally, set the content size of your UIScrollView in the viewDidLoad method. Something like this:

```
_scrollView.ContentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 640.0);
```

Please note that the first number means the width and the second means the height of your scroll view's content and you can change them depending of your wishes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UITableView, with cell where you put UITextField's. When user tap on textField you have to register notify of keyboard appear (some hints there [keyboard notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901174/ios-nsnotificationcenter-multiple-uikeyboard-notification) ) and change tableview frame to adjust to keyboard.